# Jpeg images are zoomed and ORF files are not in Lightroom 5

Tags: lightroom, raw, jpeg, olympus

I am using Lightroom 5 and imported jpeg and raw images from my OMD EM1 shot with the 12-40mm kit zoom lens.  Some of the jpeg images seem to be zoomed while the raw (orf) images are not for the same file number.  I have done no processing in Lightroom 5 to any of the images. I checked the metadata and both the jpeg and orf files and they show the same focal length.  This happened for about 25 images in the middle of the shooting day.  The 60 previous images all show the same image for jpeg and raw as do the 150 images shot after.  Any idea why these 25 images differ between jpeg and orf?

Comment: Could you give some sample images showing how significant the zoom is?

Comment: What naming convention did you use on import? are the image numbers straight off the camera, or generated by Lightroom? And did you delete any images off the camera during shooting (I'm not familiar with the camera, nor sure how Lightroom indexes, nor how you may have handled the photos, but perhaps if one was deleted but not its matching ORF they could have gotten out of sync?)

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely the software-based automatic distortion correction of your camera. If a distortion correction is applied you lose some part of the frame on it's borders and this could give you a little "zoomed in" like effect.

The RAW-Files of your camera seem to be really "raw" so no correction is applied and therefore no loss on the borders.

You can read more about the correction in [this review](http://robinwong.blogspot.de/2013/10/olympus-omd-e-m1-review-comparison-with.html).